# Java.exe exited with code 1 Xamarin.Android and ProGuard

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `Xamarin.Android` application. I tried to enable `ProGuard` and when I do, I get the archive process has failed issue which states that `Java.exe` has exited with code 1. When I turn off `ProGuard`, this error does not happen, which is good.

My question is, why does `ProGuard` cause this? One thing I noticed in researching the issue it to make sure that `ProGuard` is up to date and that you are using the correct `JDK`. This is where things get interesting, I had just done a fresh installation of `VS2017` with all updates. What I noticed is in the newest version of VS, there is by default a replacement to `JDK` named `microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.9`.

Because it defaulted to this, I have left it. Technically, I could download `JDK 1.8` and change the development kit location to point to `JDK` instead of the Microsoft one.

I suspect that this is all new and I have not seen much documentation on this but it seems reasonable that `ProGuard` is not supported in the Microsoft replacement to the JDK, `microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.9`. Furthermore, I would like to know if that is true, is it because the Microsoft version does `ProGuard` internally by default or do we just not have that option?

This is one thing I wish was a bit more thought out, explained or documented so I don't have to sit here and figure it out.

Anybody have some answers?

Thanks!

Comment: MSFT's OpenJDK runs Proguard without any problems... Enable diagnostic level msbuild logging and review the full error, it will provide the details needed to help (lots of times it is your proguard file as if you created it with VS, it has a unicode BOM header that proguard will error on, it could be that the Java stack size needs increasing, etc...) Also you can look the newly supported D8/R8 (I have projects it works fine in and others that are complete failures using it, so buyer beware) : https://blog.xamarin.com/androids-d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker/

Comment: I have a detailed blog on D8/R8 if you are interested https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/a-deep-dive-into-androids-d8-dexer-and-r8-shrinker-with-xamarin-ca66e00b1c8d